# how check if parameter are null and ckecks it in the query

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, where-clause

Suppose to have 3 date in input, data1 and data2 are the interval and data3 is a generical input dates. data1 and data2 can be null, data3 is not null. So I can have 3 situtation :

1. data3 > data1 (data2 is null)
2. data3 < data2 (data1 is null)
3. data1 < data3 < data2

I don't want create a different if with different queries. I want create a query that handles these cases.

Suppose to have a table empolyes(id primary key, registration_date), suppose I have two Dates in input, how I must do to resolve my problem?

Comment: hi, we need more info: 1) add some code showing us what have you done with java 2) which db is ?

Comment: share sample table and its expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this explicitly:

```
where (data3 > date1 or date1 is null) and
      (date3 < date2 or date2 is null)
```

You can also use some form of `coalesce()`, such as:

```
where date3 > coalesce(date1, date3 - interval '1 day') and
      date3 < coalesce(date2, date3 + interval '1 day')
```

Personally, I find the first version more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using following line of code in where clause:

(...) WHERE data3 BETWEEN NVL(data1, data3) AND NVL(data2, data3)

EDIT: I believe that, when working with dates, handling cases when date3 is equal to date1 (or date2, respectively) is mandatory rather then optional and BETWEEN AND also handle those cases.

Comment: This is a reasonable suggestion, but `between` includes the bounds (`>=` and `<=`), so the logic is not the same as what the OP is asking for.